# angular controller doesn't work after page changed

Tags: facebook, angularjs

I have an angular app generated by yeoman,and it has two pages.
And I set a routeProvider for these two pages:

```
angular.module('fbPostApp', [
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngRoute'
])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
    $routeProvider
      .when('/friend-filter', {
        templateUrl: 'views/friend-filter.html',
        controller: 'FriendFilterCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

MainCtrl:

```
function MainCtrl($scope,$http) {

        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId      : 'Myid',
                status     : true, // check login status
                cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
            });
                $scope.login = function(){
                    FB.login(function(response) {
                        $scope.uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                        $scope.accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                        login_success($scope.uid,$scope.accessToken);
                    });
                }
        ................
            };
        };
    };
```

FriendFilterCtrl:

```
function FriendFilterCtrl($scope,$http) {

        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId      : 'Myid',
                status     : true, // check login status
                cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
            });
                $scope.login = function(){
                    FB.login(function(response) {
                        $scope.uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                        $scope.accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                        login_success($scope.uid,$scope.accessToken);
                    });
                }
        ................
            };
        };
    }
```

My link:

```
<a href="#/main">Main</a>
<a href="#/friend-filter">Friend</a>
```

When I get into both pages their controllers work very well(Login with your Facebook).However, if I "switch" to another page by link,I can get the page's template but it won't do anything.
So I want to ask that is there anything I missed or did wrong cause this situation?

Comment: Post your `<a>` tag or whatever you use to redirect.

Comment: Also, you're missing a `'` after `.controller('FriendFilterCtrl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code outside of any angular controller:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'Myid',
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });
};
```

Your controller(s) should now look like:

```
angular.module('fbPostApp').controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope,$http) {
    $scope.login = function(){
        FB.login(function(response) {
            $scope.uid = response.authResponse.userID;
            $scope.accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            login_success($scope.uid,$scope.accessToken);
        });
    }
    ................
}])
```

---

**Note:** if you have a global Facebook login button, you shouldn't copy your `$scope.login` function to every single controller in the app. Learn about [angular directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Comment: Actually....the controller I post before is not working, the edited one is what I use in my app now,sorry.
But your advise did work!!!!